# My template doesn't recognize a variable. Why does this occur?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

My handlebars template has something like this:

`Template.test.people`

```
<template name="test">
<ul>
    {{#each people}}
         {{ name }} //name is present in every object in the Template.test.people array.
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

The `Template.test.people` variable is instantiated (`Template.test.people = [...]`) at some point during runtime when the user clicks on a button. At which time, the above unordered list becomes unhidden. The list however displays as an empty list!

However, even though I can go to the console and read the value of the `Template.test.people` variable, at this time, and can clearly see that it has information. The variable is an array of objects.

I tried another workaround just to make sure that things were getting "updated", and I passed my variable through a function like so:

```
Template.test.helper = function(){
   return Template.test.people;
}
```

and then change the template to this:

```
<template name="test">
<ul>
    {{#each helper}}
         {{ name }}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

which also did not work.

Comment: How are you calling your template? Can you show use the `test.people` array - should look something like `[{name:'alfa'}, {name:'beta'}]`

Answer (score 2):

Simply reassigning static template data does not trigger any kind of reactive recalculation. Store the objects in `Session`, a collection, or another reactive data source:

```
Template.test.people = function() {
  return Session.get( "people" );
};

Template.test.events({
  "click #the-button": function() {
    Session.set( "people", [{ foo: "bar" }, { baz: "qux" }] );
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not at my system right now, but, I did try that first. When I attempted this, I got a weird "PostMessage fail" error that had something to do with me toggling my embedded iframe for YouTube. So using Session is not option.

Comment: That error message doesn't sound like it has anything to do with how the data is being updated. The problem is how ever you're handling your YouTube embeds. Can you post that code? Right now the template data isn't getting updated at all, because nothing you're doing triggers a recomputation.

Comment: Sure thing, as soon as I get a chance. I`ll put it up an an hour.